# What Mitzvot Can A Non-Jew Not Keep?

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah, noahidism

What commandments, including any minhagim and the like, are Non-Jews ***ABSOLUTELY forbidden*** from keeping (*in its entirety*)?

A famous one is the prohibition of keeping Shabbat, EVEN for a a Non-Jew that is in the process of conversion (*in its entirety*).

Besides Shabbat, are there any other commandments that are forbidden for Non-Jews, ***under the assumptions***:

- They are well learned in the laws regarding said mitzvah
- They do it for their own (*the mitzvah’s*) sake, whether during conversion process, mitzvah is logically appealing, etc.

Regarding the above, **what would be the difference?** (*if any*):

- They live alone
- They live with Non-Jews
- They live with Jews

Comment: None. As a purely jurisdictional matter, they are not obligated to obey biblical or rabbinic law, so even if something is explicitly forbidden to a gentile there, they don't have to listen to that prohibition.

Comment: @Shmuel Slightly, but the answer brought by EhevuTov and the comment Mike made, makes the “halachic” decision even more confusing. It seems to me a God-fearing Non-Jew would, in a sense, adhere to Rabbinic Judaism but then which Rabbi is to be relied upon? Can a Non-Jew themself deem which Rabbi one would like to follow? (assuming a Non-Jew wouldn’t be either sefardic or ashkenaz for example)

Comment: @JewishContext. Difficult. Regarding a Jew, you are not supposed to go Rav shopping, to go to Rav 1 for a certain decision and 2 for another one. One is supposed to "cling" to one Rav he personally knows.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and is actually heavily debated. I know Rambam rules a non-Jew cannot keep Shabbat or don tefillin, but I know there are those who disagree with him. It’s not so cut-and-dry.

Comment: Those *mitzvos* that constitute a *bris* between Hashem and the *benei yisrael*.